# Updating primary keys in POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a database from previous project that I want to use in another project, from security reasons I need to update the IDs of one of the table. Problem is that the table is heavily referenced by foreign keys from other tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "table_table" (
     "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     "created" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
);


CREATE TABLE "table_photo" (
     "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     "table_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "table_table" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
);
```

Now if I change the id on table_table the reference from table_photo won't work. 
I will probably use something like this to change the IDs:

```
UPDATE table_table SET id = id + 15613;
```

I have read somewhere that I could use ON UPDATE CASCADE constraints to do this but I am not very sure how to use it.

btw: I am using Django ORM.

Comment: Good on you for including table definitions. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Get the constraint name with `\d "table_photo"`, which shows:

```
Foreign-key constraints:
    "table_photo_table_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (table_id) REFERENCES table_table(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Then replace it with a constraint that has `on update cascade`:

```
ALTER TABLE "table_photo"
  DROP CONSTRAINT "table_photo_table_id_fkey",
  ADD CONSTRAINT "table_photo_table_id_fkey" 
    FOREIGN KEY ("table_id")
    REFERENCES "table_table"
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

Now when you do your `UPDATE`, referenced row IDs are automatically updated. Adding an index on `"table_photo"."table_id"` will help *a lot*.

---

This can be slow for big tables though. An alternative if you have large tables is to do it in a couple of stages. For table `A` with field `id` that's referenced by table `B`'s field `A_id`:

- Add a new column, `new_id`, to `A`, with a `UNIQUE` constraint. Leave it nullable.
- Add a new column, `A_new_id` to table `B`, giving it a foreign key constraint to `A(new_id)`.
- Populate `A.new_id` with the new values
- Do an

  ```
  UPDATE B
  SET A_new_id = A.new_id 
  FROM A
  WHERE B.A_id = A.id;
  ```

  to do a joined update, setting the new ID values in `B.A_new_id` to match.
- Drop the column `B.A_id` and rename `B.A_new_id` to `B.A_id`.
- Drop the column `A.id` and rename `A.new_id` to `A.id`
- Create a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint on the renamed `A.id`, `USING` the index created automatically before.

It's a lot more complicated, especially since for big tables you usually want to do each of these steps in batches.

If this seems too complicated, just do it with a cascading foreign key constraint like above.

Comment: I had to separate ADD and DROP constraints to its own alter statements but it worked.

Comment: Needs a comma between the drop constraint and add constraint otherwise you'll get a syntax error - I'll edit it in

Comment: After update, do we need to do any reset for changed constraint ```ON UPDATE CASCADE```?